# Activity animation not working in Galaxy Tab

Tags: android

I am using xml for activity transition, it working in all device as well as Samsung phone, but same thing is not working in samsung galaxy Tab. Can any help me out why this is happening, what should i do?

**i am using following code:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TabletAnimActivity.this,Next.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);
```

**push_left_in:**

```
set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="5000"
    alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1600" 
set
```

**push_left_out**

```
set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="5000"
    alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="1600" 
set
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overridePendingTransition api seems to fail in all samsung devices (tried galaxy ace/s/tab). Even the android sdk api demo (ApiDemos/app/activity/animation) for overridePendingTransition fails on these.

Comment: any alternative for this for samsung devices ?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a little late, but for those such as myself who are struggling with this:

On all Samsung devices, TouchWiz disables animations in 2 ways depending on the android version.

1. Version `< 4.0` - Disables animations in `Settings > Display > Animations > Off` -- Change to `On`
2. Version `>= 4.0` - Disables animations in `Developer Options > Drawing > Animator Duration Scale > Animation scale x0` -- Change to `Animation Scale x1`

Hope this helps anyone in this situation.

Comment: wait! would all the app users have to set this option?

Comment: Yes, it would have to be changed by the user in order for animations to be shown.

Comment: and why it's not activated by default?

Comment: That is a question for Samsung.

Answer (score 6):

Animations are by default turned off in samsung phones

Go to Settings -> display -> animations  and then turn on the All animations and you will be able to see the animations

Comment: That was it. Why put in all that effort to animate stuff if the user doesn't want them to be shown?!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check with on the galaxy device is a settings that the user can remove window animations.