# Activity Transition Animation not working from Tab Activity To any other Activity

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to use activity transition animaition using OverridePendingTransition
The same code works while I move from 1 activity to another everywhere in my App
But when I use the same while transitioning from an activity which is a part of tab
to any other activity. The animation does not work and the standard animation takes place

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(xxx.this,
                yyy.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
```

here xxx is the class which is one of the tabs activity class and yyy is any activity class

I am stuck
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Cheers
Himanshu

Comment: i saw this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453191/activity-animation-not-working-in-galaxy-tab

:(

Comment: I reported the same to google issues and the workaround provided was :- I have found a way to work arround this, it is not perfect but it works.
I add the overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
before the onPause on the TabActivity.

public void onPause() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    super.onPause()
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported the same to google issues and the workaround provided was(I have not tried it though) :- I have found a way to work arround this, it is not perfect but it works.
I add the overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
before the onPause on the TabActivity.

```
public void onPause() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    super.onPause()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to make it work:

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
         public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
         {
                View selectedView = getTabHost().getCurrentView();
                if (getTabHost().getCurrentTab() > lastTab)
                {
                    selectedView .setAnimation( R.anim.slide_left_in );
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedView .setAnimation( R.anim.slide_left_out );
                }

                lastTab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
         }
    });
```