# Android The Slide_from_top_out animation not work on the tablet issue

Tags: android

I have made the following animation in my android project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
   <translate 
      android:fromYDelta="0" 
      android:toYDelta="-100%" 
      android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

which is making the dissappear starting the bottom to top.
I used

`overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_from_top_out)`

to start this animation,
it works successfully in the android 2.3.3(htc desire S), but it can not work on the 
android 3.1(samsung tablet), others animations(like from_top_bottom, it's same as this animation, just different with the direction) can work successfully in the tablet and phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe casued by [Activity animation not working in Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453191/activity-animation-not-working-in-galaxy-tab)
, I tested my codes in the ASUS tablet, it always worked succesfully, so i think maybe this animation just failed in the samsung.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax might not be completely correct.

Your using a set, even though you only have one animation, your missing the units from your yDelta. Here's what I do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: It also not worked on the tablet, and i think my animation is the same as yours worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **Settings** -> **Developer Options** -> Change **Window animation scale** to .5x. Do the same with **Translation animation scale** and **Animator duration scale**. Seems like these devices has by default turned off these options.

Comment: I Tried but, No Luck Man!